# Growth mixture modelling with unequal number of measurements per individual

Tags: modeling, growth-mixture-model

I have responses to a questionnaire item from a number of people, measured at equidistant timepoints. I wish to fit a growth mixture model (in `R`, using the `LCMM` package) to this data to find latent classes. My data looks something like this:

```
    ID  item-response  timepoint
    -----------------------
    1       3           1
    1       2           2
    1       2           3
    2       2           1
    2       3           2
    2       2           3
    2       1           4
    2       1           5
    2       3           6
    2       2           7
    2       2           8
    2       2           9
    2       1           10
    2       4           11
    2       2           12
    3       1           1
    3       1           2
    3       1           3
    3       1           4
    3       1           5
    .       .           .
    .       .           .
    .       .           .
```

The item is one of 13 on a questionnaire on mood states. Responses are given on a Likert-scale (1 to 5).

A plot of the response curves of the first four individuals looks like this:
[image: Response curves of the first four individuals]

I am worried about the fact that the number of measurements per person is not the same. Is this a huge problem for growth mixture models or not so much?

**[edit] included a column of timepoints**

Comment: What is the x-axis in this plot? Is there a "time" associated with each of the repeated measurements?

Comment: The x-axis denote time. Measurements were taken each week.

Comment: The layout of your data set at the top of the post does not include the time variable. Do you have this information?

Comment: I've added a column of timepoints to make the data more clear. As you can see, the person with ID 1 only has three measurements, while ID 2 has twelve. So at some point, certain individuals stopped, while others kept providing measurements. (Question: do we call data like this *censored data*?)

Comment: Are these data responses to a Likert-type item? If so, could you please tell us a little more on the questionnaire that's being used?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I forgot to mention it's Likert-type data. I've updated the question.

Comment: I would be mainly concerned by measurement error at the level of a single item, not with unbalanced data unless you can't assume data are missing at random.